# I am not able to query an exact date match

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2013

The second query(the commented one) without the date field works fine.

```
Try
        con.Open()
        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        Dim Combocolumn As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
        Dim frm_date As Date

        Combocolumn.HeaderText = "Overtime Hrs"
        Combocolumn.Name = "ovr_hrs"
        row = New ArrayList()
        row.Add("4")
        row.Add("3.5")
        row.Add("3")
        row.Add("2.5")
        row.Add("2")
        row.Add("1.5")
        row.Add("1")
        row.Add("0.5")
        row.Add("0")

        frm_date = dtp4.Value.Date     ' dtp is a DateTimePicker
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select a.emp_id as Employee_Id, b.emp_name as Employee_Name from awipl_ea a, awipl_emp_info b WHERE a.emp_id = b.emp_id AND a.sft = " & cb18.SelectedIndex + 1 & " AND a.dept =  " & txt27.Text & " AND a.dt = '" & frm_date.Date & "'", con)

        'da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select a.emp_id as Employee_Id, b.emp_name as Employee_Name from awipl_ea a, awipl_emp_info b WHERE a.emp_id = b.emp_id AND a.sft = " & cb18.SelectedIndex + 1 & " AND a.dept =  " & txt27.Text & " ", con)

        cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlStr, con)
        da.Fill(dt)
        dgv1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView
        Combocolumn.Items.AddRange(row.ToArray())
        dgv1.Columns.Add(Combocolumn)
        dgv1.Columns(1).ReadOnly = True
        dgv1.Columns(2).ReadOnly = False
        dgv1.Columns(0).ReadOnly = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try
```

Comment: Use [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter.aspx). Don't force everything to be converted into a string.

Comment: You'll also note I've edited your title quite a bit - technology information belongs in the tags, not the title, and we hope everyone here appreciates having their questions answered, so it doesn't need to be said.

Comment: How to use parameters in such a scenario. please help

Answer (score 0):

In order to use dates in the Where clause of a query, you need to use the hash sign `#`.

Like so :

```
" Select a.emp_id as Employee_Id, b.emp_name as Employee_Name from awipl_ea a, " & _
" awipl_emp_info b WHERE a.emp_id = b.emp_id AND a.sft = " & _
 cb18.SelectedIndex + 1 & " AND a.dept =  " & _
 txt27.Text & " AND a.dt = #" & frm_date.Date & "#"
```